# Is my solution of $\lim _{n\to\infty} \frac{1^e+2^e+\cdots +n^e}{n^{e+1}}$ correct?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, proof-verification, riemann-integration

It is required that we recognize Riemann's sum.
$$\lim _{n\to\infty} \frac{1^e+2^e+\cdots +n^e}{n^{e+1}}$$
$$\lim _{n \to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( \frac{k}{n} \right)^e$$
$$ \int_0^{1} x^e dx =\frac{1}{e+1}$$

Thank you.

Comment: Yep. Looks correct.

Comment: @Vizag Thank you. Should I wait for someone (maybe you) to reply so I could accept the answer, or should I reply&accept myself so the question won't be hanging unanswered?

Comment: Me saying "Looks Correct" isn't an answer. It doesn't matter if it just stays there so don't worry.

Comment: It's true for $e>-1$ because function $f(x)=x^{e+1}$ is not defined at $x=0$ (and $f(x)$ is unbounded $x=0$).

Comment: I also recommend not to use symbol $e$ as an arbitrary constant (at least in calculus) because it usually refers to $e=2.71828...$ (limit of $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$).

Comment: 1) The Riemann sum argument works for $e \ge 0$. 2) The Riemann sum argument fails for $e < 0$ but the limit do equal to $\frac{1}{e+1}$  as long as $e > -1$. You can prove that using [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)
 3) the limit diverges to $+\infty$ when $e \le -1$,